# Scenic Ribbon won't show up in Delphi Form // Has anybody an idea?

Tags: delphi, windows-ribbon-framework, scenic-ribbon

i've played a little bit with the Scenic Ribbon API ([Windows Ribbon Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371191%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)). This is my result:

```
program RibTest;

uses
  Windows,
  Messages,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj;

{$R 'e:\ribbon\test.res'}

type
  UI_VIEWTYPE = (UI_VIEWTYPE_RIBBON = 1);
  UI_VIEWVERB = (UI_VIEWVERB_CREATE = 0, UI_VIEWVERB_DESTROY = 1,
                  UI_VIEWVERB_SIZE = 2, UI_VIEWVERB_ERROR = 3);
  UI_COMMANDTYPE = (UI_COMMANDTYPE_UNKNOWN = 0,
                    UI_COMMANDTYPE_GROUP = 1,
                    UI_COMMANDTYPE_ACTION = 2,
                    UI_COMMANDTYPE_ANCHOR = 3,
                    UI_COMMANDTYPE_CONTEXT = 4,
                    UI_COMMANDTYPE_COLLECTION = 5,
                    UI_COMMANDTYPE_COMMANDCOLLECTION = 6,
                    UI_COMMANDTYPE_DECIMAL = 7,
                    UI_COMMANDTYPE_BOOLEAN = 8,
                    UI_COMMANDTYPE_FONT = 9,
                    UI_COMMANDTYPE_RECENTITEMS = 10,
                    UI_COMMANDTYPE_COLORANCHOR = 11,
                    UI_COMMANDTYPE_COLORCOLLECTION = 12);

  UI_EXECUTEVERB = (UI_EXECUTIONVERB_EXECUTE = 0,
                    UI_EXECUTIONVERB_PREVIEW = 1,
                    UI_EXECUTIONVERB_CANCELPREVIEW = 2);



  IUIRibbon = interface
  ['{803982ab-370a-4f7e-a9e7-8784036a6e26}']
    function GetHeight(var CY: UInt32): HRESULT; StdCall;
    function LoadSettingsFromStream(Stream: IStream): HRESULT; StdCall;
    function SaveSettingsToStream(Stream: IStream): HRESULT; StdCall;

  end;

  IUISimplePropertySet = interface
  ['{c205bb48-5b1c-4219-a106-15bd0a5f24e2}']
    function GetValue(Key: TPropertyKey; var Value: TPropVariant): HRESULT; StdCall;
  end;

  IUICommandHandler = interface
  ['{75ae0a2d-dc03-4c9f-8883-069660d0beb6}']
    function Execute(CommandID: UInt32; Verb: UI_EXECUTEVERB; Key: TPropertyKey;
                      Value: TPropVariant; ExecProps: IUISimplePropertySet): HRESULT; StdCall;
    function UpdateProperty(CommandID: UInt32; Key: TPropertyKey; CurrValue: TPropVariant;
                            var NewValue: TPropertyKey): HRESULT; StdCall;

  end;

  IUIApplication = interface
  ['{D428903C-729A-491d-910D-682A08FF2522}']
    function OnViewChanged(ViewID: UInt32; TypeID: UI_VIEWTYPE; View: IUnknown;
                          Verb: UI_VIEWVERB; ReasonCode: Int32): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function OnCreateUICommand(CommandID: UInt32; TypeID: UI_COMMANDTYPE;
                              CommandHandler: IUICommandHandler): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function OnDestroyUICommand(CommandID: UInt32; TypeID: UI_COMMANDTYPE; 
                              CommandHandler: IUICommandHandler): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  UI_INVALIDATIONS = (UI_INVALIDATIONS_STATE = 1, UI_INVALIDATIONS_VALUE = 2,
                      UI_INVALIDATIONS_PROPERTY = 4, UI_INVALIDATIONS_ALLPROPERTIES = 8);

  IUIFramework = interface
  ['{F4F0385D-6872-43a8-AD09-4C339CB3F5C5}']
    function Initialize(FrameWnd: HWND; App: IUIApplication): HRESULT; StdCall;
    function LoadUI(Instance: Cardinal; RecName: LPCWSTR): HRESULT; StdCall;
    function GetView(ViedID: Uint32; RiID: TIID; var PPV: Pointer): HRESULT; StdCall;
    function GetUICommandProperty(CommandID: UInt32; Key: TPropertyKey; 
                     var Value: TPropVariant): HRESULT; StdCall;
    function SetUICommandProperty(CommandID: UInt32; Key: TPropertyKey; 
                     Value: TPropVariant): HRESULT; StdCall;
    function InvalidateUICommand(CommandID: UInt32; Flags: UI_INVALIDATIONS; 
                     const Key: PPropertyKey): HRESULT; StdCall;
    function FlushPendingInvalidations: HRESULT; StdCall;
    function SetModes(iModes: Int32): HRESULT; StdCall;

  end;

  TTest = class(TInterfacedObject, IUIApplication)
  public
    function OnViewChanged(ViewID: UInt32; TypeID: UI_VIEWTYPE; View: IUnknown;
                          Verb: UI_VIEWVERB; ReasonCode: Int32): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function OnCreateUICommand(CommandID: UInt32; TypeID: UI_COMMANDTYPE;
                              CommandHandler: IUICommandHandler): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function OnDestroyUICommand(CommandID: UInt32; TypeID: UI_COMMANDTYPE;
      CommandHandler: IUICommandHandler): HRESULT; stdcall;

  end;

const
  CLSID_UIRibbonFramework: TGUID = '{926749fa-2615-4987-8845-c33e65f2b957}';

var
  MyApp: TTest;
  MeinHandle: HWND;
  tmpFrameW: IUIFramework;


function WndProc(hWnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM;
lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  Res: HRESULT;
begin
  Result := 0;
  case uMsg OF
    WM_CREATE:
      begin
        CoInitialize(nil);
        CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UIRibbonFramework, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                          IUIFramework, tmpFrameW);
          if Succeeded(tmpFrameW.Initialize(hWnd, IUIApplication(MyApp))) then
          begin
            Res := tmpFrameW.LoadUI(HInstance, PChar('APPLICATION_RIBBON'));
            if not Succeeded(Res)then
                sleep(5);
          end;
      end;
    WM_DESTROY:
      begin
        PostQuitMessage(0);
      end;
  else
    Result := DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  end;
end;


var
  wc: TWndClassEx;
  msg: TMSG;
{ TTest }

function TTest.OnCreateUICommand(CommandID: UInt32; TypeID: UI_COMMANDTYPE;
  CommandHandler: IUICommandHandler): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TTest.OnDestroyUICommand(CommandID: UInt32; TypeID: UI_COMMANDTYPE;
  CommandHandler: IUICommandHandler): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TTest.OnViewChanged(ViewID: UInt32; TypeID: UI_VIEWTYPE;
  View: IUnknown; Verb: UI_VIEWVERB; ReasonCode: Int32): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

begin
  MyApp := TTest.Create;

  wc.cbSize := SizeOf(TWndClassEx);
  wc.style := 0;
  wc.cbClsExtra := 0;
  wc.cbWndExtra := 0;
  wc.hbrBackground := COLOR_WINDOW;
  wc.lpszMenuName := nil;
  wc.lpszClassName := 'MeinRibbon';
  wc.hIconSm := 0;
  wc.hInstance := HInstance;
  wc.hIcon := LoadIcon(HInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(1));
  wc.hCursor := LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
  wc.lpfnWndProc := @WndProc;
  RegisterClassEx(wc);

  MeinHandle := CreateWindow('MeinRibbon', 'TestAPP', 
                WS_OVERLAPPED or WS_CLIPCHILDREN or WS_SYSMENU or WS_CAPTION,
                Integer(CW_USEDEFAULT), 0, Integer(CW_USEDEFAULT), 0, HWND_DESKTOP,
                0, HInstance, nil);

  ShowWindow(MeinHandle, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  UpdateWindow(MeinHandle);


  while True do
  begin
    if not GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0) then break;
    translatemessage(msg);
    dispatchmessage(msg);
  end;

  ExitCode := GetLastError;
end.
```

Everything runs without an error. I've made a resource with the Ribbon binary XML definition and it got linked correctly into my executable. But my window appears without the Ribbon.

The important part is in `WndProc`. The framework gets initialized with `tmpFrameW.Initialize` (seems to be correct). The reference counter of `MyApp` (it's my `IUIApplication` implementation) increases. With a call to `tmpFrameW.LoadUI` the Ribbon definition should be loaded. There is no error in this call (result is 0 and no exception raises) but the reference counter of `MyApp` decreases.

That's what happens... Does anybody have an idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error...

1. I'm not familiar with c or c++. (I guess) Therefore i've overlooked some asterisks and some `out`'s. So there are some incorrect params which leads to minor bugs.
2. But my main problem is the header file. In `UIRibbon.h` is the function `IUIFramework.Destroy` missing. In the online SDK and in the `UIRibbon.idl` this function is defined. I added it to my interface and now everything works like expected.